# cmyk to rgb conversion in alfresco plugin code and ImageMagick trying various way, unable to get it done. Kindly check my findings, please advice me

Tags: java, content-management-system, alfresco, imagemagick-convert, alfresco-enterprise

I am doing cmyk to rgb conversion but trying various way, unable to get it done. Kindly check my findings and please advice me,

**1. i am getting the err and warning message when running through alfresco and conversion is incorrect**

os:         Linux
   command:    /opt/alfresco-one/common/bin/convert -density 300 /opt/alfresco-one/tomcat/temp/amicmyk.tif -profile /opt/alfresco-one/cit/rgbprofile/AdobeRGB1998.icc /opt/alfresco-one/Websites/amirgb.jpg
   succeeded:  true
   exit code:  0
   out:
   err:        .convert.bin: delegate library support not built-in `/opt/alfresco-one/tomcat/temp/amicmyk.tif' (LCMS) @ warning/profile.c/ProfileImage/814.

**2. When run imagemagick command through terminal there is no error and conversion is perfect**

[alfresco-one@ABC-STG-server alfresco-one]$ /opt/alfresco-one/common/bin/convert -density 300 /opt/alfresco-one/tomcat/temp/amicmyk.tif -profile /opt/alfresco-one/cit/rgbprofile/AdobeRGB1998.icc /opt/alfresco-one/Websites/amiRgb.jpg

**3. I can see that lcms is present as in built delegate**

[alfresco-one@ABC-STG-server alfresco-one]$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-5 Q16 x86_64 2017-10-01 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig fpx freetype gslib jng jpeg lcms ltdl lzma pangocairo png ps tiff webp wmf x xml zlib

**4.
So i tried executing the imagemagick command using Runtime.exec() as below**

**If I run following program, it executed successfully and converted correctly**

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CmykToRgb {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("convert -density 300 /home/alfresco-one/cms39/amicmyk.tif -profile /opt/alfresco-one/cit/rgbprofile/AdobeRGB1998.icc /opt/alfresco-one/Websites/amirgb.jpg");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

but if i use following in my plugin code in alfresco,

```
try {      
             Map<NodeRef, Map<String, String>> temporaryFileOperationsParams = temporaryFileOperationsParamsInfo.getTemporaryFileOperationsParams();    
            //modifiedFileInfo.getNodeRef();    
            modifiedFilePath =  jBLFileFolderUtil.getFullPath(modifiedFileInfo);            
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("convert -density 300 /home/alfresco-one/cms39/amicmyk.tif -profile /opt/alfresco-one/cit/rgbprofile/AdobeRGB1998.icc /opt/alfresco-one/Websites/amirgb.jpg");    
}catch(Exception e){  
    // No exception occured  
}
```

it executed but conversion is wrong.

Could anyone please help me out how can i execute the query from alfresco plugin code.
Please dont mind my english and formatting,Many thanks in advance

*5. Below are the output of identify -verbose D:\somedir\apr17\amicmyk.tif*

```
\ImageMagick-7.0.5-2-portable-Q16-x64>identify -verbose D:\somedir\apr17\amicmyk.tif
Image: D:\somedir\apr17\amicmyk.tif
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1013x1556+0+0
  Resolution: 300x300
  Print size: 3.37667x5.18667
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: ColorSeparation
  Endianess: MSB
  Colorspace: CMYK
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Cyan: 8-bit
    Magenta: 1-bit
    Yellow: 8-bit
    Black: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 1576228
    Cyan:
      min: 218 (0.854902)
      max: 218 (0.854902)
      mean: 218 (0.854902)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 9.33343e+068
      skewness: -2.97681e+048
      entropy: -1.#IND
    Magenta:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 0 (0)
      mean: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: -3
      skewness: 0
      entropy: -1.#IND
    Yellow:
      min: 166 (0.65098)
      max: 166 (0.65098)
      mean: 166 (0.65098)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 2.50431e+068
      skewness: -1.27137e+048
      entropy: -1.#IND
    Black:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 40.888 (0.160345)
      standard deviation: 84.4223 (0.331068)
      kurtosis: 1.66544
      skewness: 1.8432
      entropy: 0.401228
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 106.222 (0.416557)
      standard deviation: 98.4207 (0.385963)
      kurtosis: -1.81676
      skewness: -0.0406692
      entropy: -1.#IND
  Total ink density: 250.588%
  Colors: 256
  Histogram:
    978556: (218,  0,166,  0) #DA00A600 cmyk(218,0,166,0)
    107193: (218,  0,166,255) #DA00A6FF cmyk(218,0,166,255)
     75274: (218,  0,166,  1) #DA00A601 cmyk(218,0,166,1)
     43544: (218,  0,166,  2) #DA00A602 cmyk(218,0,166,2)
     29469: (218,  0,166,  3) #DA00A603 cmyk(218,0,166,3)
     21740: (218,  0,166,  4) #DA00A604 cmyk(218,0,166,4)
     16121: (218,  0,166,  5) #DA00A605 cmyk(218,0,166,5)
     11862: (218,  0,166,  6) #DA00A606 cmyk(218,0,166,6)
      9124: (218,  0,166,  7) #DA00A607 cmyk(218,0,166,7)
      8481: (218,  0,166,254) #DA00A6FE cmyk(218,0,166,254)
      7197: (218,  0,166,  8) #DA00A608 cmyk(218,0,166,8)
      6618: (218,  0,166, 64) #DA00A640 cmyk(218,0,166,64)
      6028: (218,  0,166,  9) #DA00A609 cmyk(218,0,166,9)
      5365: (218,  0,166,253) #DA00A6FD cmyk(218,0,166,253)
      5011: (218,  0,166, 10) #DA00A60A cmyk(218,0,166,10)
      4279: (218,  0,166, 11) #DA00A60B cmyk(218,0,166,11)
      3992: (218,  0,166,252) #DA00A6FC cmyk(218,0,166,252)
      3799: (218,  0,166, 12) #DA00A60C cmyk(218,0,166,12)
      3313: (218,  0,166, 16) #DA00A610 cmyk(218,0,166,16)
      3291: (218,  0,166,251) #DA00A6FB cmyk(218,0,166,251)
      3286: (218,  0,166, 13) #DA00A60D cmyk(218,0,166,13)
      2925: (218,  0,166, 14) #DA00A60E cmyk(218,0,166,14)
      2878: (218,  0,166,250) #DA00A6FA cmyk(218,0,166,250)
      2666: (218,  0,166, 15) #DA00A60F cmyk(218,0,166,15)
      2467: (218,  0,166,249) #DA00A6F9 cmyk(218,0,166,249)
      2437: (218,  0,166,191) #DA00A6BF cmyk(218,0,166,191)
      2285: (218,  0,166,248) #DA00A6F8 cmyk(218,0,166,248)
      2281: (218,  0,166, 17) #DA00A611 cmyk(218,0,166,17)
      2207: (218,  0,166,239) #DA00A6EF cmyk(218,0,166,239)
      2135: (218,  0,166,247) #DA00A6F7 cmyk(218,0,166,247)
      2120: (218,  0,166,128) #DA00A680 cmyk(218,0,166,128)
      2089: (218,  0,166, 18) #DA00A612 cmyk(218,0,166,18)
      2014: (218,  0,166,246) #DA00A6F6 cmyk(218,0,166,246)
      1943: (218,  0,166,245) #DA00A6F5 cmyk(218,0,166,245)
      1877: (218,  0,166, 19) #DA00A613 cmyk(218,0,166,19)
      1845: (218,  0,166, 20) #DA00A614 cmyk(218,0,166,20)
      1744: (218,  0,166,244) #DA00A6F4 cmyk(218,0,166,244)
      1736: (218,  0,166,243) #DA00A6F3 cmyk(218,0,166,243)
      1704: (218,  0,166, 32) #DA00A620 cmyk(218,0,166,32)
      1641: (218,  0,166, 21) #DA00A615 cmyk(218,0,166,21)
      1612: (218,  0,166, 22) #DA00A616 cmyk(218,0,166,22)
      1580: (218,  0,166,241) #DA00A6F1 cmyk(218,0,166,241)
      1530: (218,  0,166,242) #DA00A6F2 cmyk(218,0,166,242)
      1501: (218,  0,166,238) #DA00A6EE cmyk(218,0,166,238)
      1489: (218,  0,166, 48) #DA00A630 cmyk(218,0,166,48)
      1487: (218,  0,166, 24) #DA00A618 cmyk(218,0,166,24)
      1483: (218,  0,166,207) #DA00A6CF cmyk(218,0,166,207)
      1464: (218,  0,166,240) #DA00A6F0 cmyk(218,0,166,240)
      1460: (218,  0,166, 23) #DA00A617 cmyk(218,0,166,23)
      1427: (218,  0,166,223) #DA00A6DF cmyk(218,0,166,223)
      1397: (218,  0,166,236) #DA00A6EC cmyk(218,0,166,236)
      1379: (218,  0,166, 96) #DA00A660 cmyk(218,0,166,96)
      1372: (218,  0,166,237) #DA00A6ED cmyk(218,0,166,237)
      1362: (218,  0,166, 26) #DA00A61A cmyk(218,0,166,26)
      1347: (218,  0,166,233) #DA00A6E9 cmyk(218,0,166,233)
      1337: (218,  0,166,159) #DA00A69F cmyk(218,0,166,159)
      1324: (218,  0,166, 27) #DA00A61B cmyk(218,0,166,27)
      1324: (218,  0,166, 25) #DA00A619 cmyk(218,0,166,25)
      1301: (218,  0,166,235) #DA00A6EB cmyk(218,0,166,235)
      1288: (218,  0,166,234) #DA00A6EA cmyk(218,0,166,234)
      1278: (218,  0,166,231) #DA00A6E7 cmyk(218,0,166,231)
      1247: (218,  0,166,232) #DA00A6E8 cmyk(218,0,166,232)
      1219: (218,  0,166, 28) #DA00A61C cmyk(218,0,166,28)
      1207: (218,  0,166, 29) #DA00A61D cmyk(218,0,166,29)
      1174: (218,  0,166,228) #DA00A6E4 cmyk(218,0,166,228)
      1173: (218,  0,166,230) #DA00A6E6 cmyk(218,0,166,230)
      1162: (218,  0,166,229) #DA00A6E5 cmyk(218,0,166,229)
      1160: (218,  0,166, 31) #DA00A61F cmyk(218,0,166,31)
      1123: (218,  0,166,143) #DA00A68F cmyk(218,0,166,143)
      1116: (218,  0,166, 30) #DA00A61E cmyk(218,0,166,30)
      1100: (218,  0,166,226) #DA00A6E2 cmyk(218,0,166,226)
      1091: (218,  0,166, 33) #DA00A621 cmyk(218,0,166,33)
      1084: (218,  0,166,224) #DA00A6E0 cmyk(218,0,166,224)
      1080: (218,  0,166,225) #DA00A6E1 cmyk(218,0,166,225)
      1068: (218,  0,166,175) #DA00A6AF cmyk(218,0,166,175)
      1065: (218,  0,166,222) #DA00A6DE cmyk(218,0,166,222)
      1045: (218,  0,166, 34) #DA00A622 cmyk(218,0,166,34)
      1036: (218,  0,166,112) #DA00A670 cmyk(218,0,166,112)
      1034: (218,  0,166,219) #DA00A6DB cmyk(218,0,166,219)
      1031: (218,  0,166,227) #DA00A6E3 cmyk(218,0,166,227)
      1030: (218,  0,166, 35) #DA00A623 cmyk(218,0,166,35)
      1022: (218,  0,166, 80) #DA00A650 cmyk(218,0,166,80)
      1017: (218,  0,166,221) #DA00A6DD cmyk(218,0,166,221)
      1005: (218,  0,166,220) #DA00A6DC cmyk(218,0,166,220)
       997: (218,  0,166,217) #DA00A6D9 cmyk(218,0,166,217)
       969: (218,  0,166,215) #DA00A6D7 cmyk(218,0,166,215)
       949: (218,  0,166, 36) #DA00A624 cmyk(218,0,166,36)
       948: (218,  0,166,218) #DA00A6DA cmyk(218,0,166,218)
       947: (218,  0,166, 39) #DA00A627 cmyk(218,0,166,39)
       941: (218,  0,166, 38) #DA00A626 cmyk(218,0,166,38)
       938: (218,  0,166,213) #DA00A6D5 cmyk(218,0,166,213)
       937: (218,  0,166, 37) #DA00A625 cmyk(218,0,166,37)
       936: (218,  0,166, 40) #DA00A628 cmyk(218,0,166,40)
       930: (218,  0,166,214) #DA00A6D6 cmyk(218,0,166,214)
       927: (218,  0,166,209) #DA00A6D1 cmyk(218,0,166,209)
       915: (218,  0,166,216) #DA00A6D8 cmyk(218,0,166,216)
       905: (218,  0,166, 42) #DA00A62A cmyk(218,0,166,42)
       889: (218,  0,166, 41) #DA00A629 cmyk(218,0,166,41)
       887: (218,  0,166,210) #DA00A6D2 cmyk(218,0,166,210)
       879: (218,  0,166,208) #DA00A6D0 cmyk(218,0,166,208)
       878: (218,  0,166,206) #DA00A6CE cmyk(218,0,166,206)
       875: (218,  0,166, 44) #DA00A62C cmyk(218,0,166,44)
       860: (218,  0,166,205) #DA00A6CD cmyk(218,0,166,205)
       857: (218,  0,166,211) #DA00A6D3 cmyk(218,0,166,211)
       857: (218,  0,166,204) #DA00A6CC cmyk(218,0,166,204)
       856: (218,  0,166,212) #DA00A6D4 cmyk(218,0,166,212)
       841: (218,  0,166,203) #DA00A6CB cmyk(218,0,166,203)
       841: (218,  0,166,199) #DA00A6C7 cmyk(218,0,166,199)
       823: (218,  0,166,201) #DA00A6C9 cmyk(218,0,166,201)
       822: (218,  0,166, 46) #DA00A62E cmyk(218,0,166,46)
       818: (218,  0,166, 45) #DA00A62D cmyk(218,0,166,45)
       814: (218,  0,166, 47) #DA00A62F cmyk(218,0,166,47)
       813: (218,  0,166,190) #DA00A6BE cmyk(218,0,166,190)
       808: (218,  0,166, 58) #DA00A63A cmyk(218,0,166,58)
       804: (218,  0,166, 43) #DA00A62B cmyk(218,0,166,43)
       803: (218,  0,166,185) #DA00A6B9 cmyk(218,0,166,185)
       803: (218,  0,166,174) #DA00A6AE cmyk(218,0,166,174)
       799: (218,  0,166, 52) #DA00A634 cmyk(218,0,166,52)
       792: (218,  0,166,202) #DA00A6CA cmyk(218,0,166,202)
       790: (218,  0,166,186) #DA00A6BA cmyk(218,0,166,186)
       790: (218,  0,166,197) #DA00A6C5 cmyk(218,0,166,197)
       788: (218,  0,166,187) #DA00A6BB cmyk(218,0,166,187)
       788: (218,  0,166, 51) #DA00A633 cmyk(218,0,166,51)
       786: (218,  0,166,195) #DA00A6C3 cmyk(218,0,166,195)
       786: (218,  0,166, 53) #DA00A635 cmyk(218,0,166,53)
       783: (218,  0,166, 49) #DA00A631 cmyk(218,0,166,49)
       782: (218,  0,166,198) #DA00A6C6 cmyk(218,0,166,198)
       779: (218,  0,166,196) #DA00A6C4 cmyk(218,0,166,196)
       779: (218,  0,166, 60) #DA00A63C cmyk(218,0,166,60)
       776: (218,  0,166,176) #DA00A6B0 cmyk(218,0,166,176)
       775: (218,  0,166,188) #DA00A6BC cmyk(218,0,166,188)
       775: (218,  0,166,194) #DA00A6C2 cmyk(218,0,166,194)
       773: (218,  0,166,184) #DA00A6B8 cmyk(218,0,166,184)
       773: (218,  0,166,200) #DA00A6C8 cmyk(218,0,166,200)
       772: (218,  0,166,178) #DA00A6B2 cmyk(218,0,166,178)
       770: (218,  0,166, 50) #DA00A632 cmyk(218,0,166,50)
       767: (218,  0,166,171) #DA00A6AB cmyk(218,0,166,171)
       767: (218,  0,166,164) #DA00A6A4 cmyk(218,0,166,164)
       766: (218,  0,166,182) #DA00A6B6 cmyk(218,0,166,182)
       765: (218,  0,166,189) #DA00A6BD cmyk(218,0,166,189)
       765: (218,  0,166,193) #DA00A6C1 cmyk(218,0,166,193)
       759: (218,  0,166, 54) #DA00A636 cmyk(218,0,166,54)
       758: (218,  0,166,183) #DA00A6B7 cmyk(218,0,166,183)
       753: (218,  0,166, 62) #DA00A63E cmyk(218,0,166,62)
       752: (218,  0,166,173) #DA00A6AD cmyk(218,0,166,173)
       751: (218,  0,166,192) #DA00A6C0 cmyk(218,0,166,192)
       749: (218,  0,166,160) #DA00A6A0 cmyk(218,0,166,160)
       746: (218,  0,166,162) #DA00A6A2 cmyk(218,0,166,162)
       746: (218,  0,166, 63) #DA00A63F cmyk(218,0,166,63)
       741: (218,  0,166,163) #DA00A6A3 cmyk(218,0,166,163)
       740: (218,  0,166,168) #DA00A6A8 cmyk(218,0,166,168)
       740: (218,  0,166,177) #DA00A6B1 cmyk(218,0,166,177)
       739: (218,  0,166, 57) #DA00A639 cmyk(218,0,166,57)
       738: (218,  0,166,180) #DA00A6B4 cmyk(218,0,166,180)
       737: (218,  0,166, 61) #DA00A63D cmyk(218,0,166,61)
       735: (218,  0,166, 59) #DA00A63B cmyk(218,0,166,59)
       731: (218,  0,166,170) #DA00A6AA cmyk(218,0,166,170)
       730: (218,  0,166, 56) #DA00A638 cmyk(218,0,166,56)
       730: (218,  0,166, 55) #DA00A637 cmyk(218,0,166,55)
       728: (218,  0,166,126) #DA00A67E cmyk(218,0,166,126)
       727: (218,  0,166,166) #DA00A6A6 cmyk(218,0,166,166)
       725: (218,  0,166,169) #DA00A6A9 cmyk(218,0,166,169)
       723: (218,  0,166,108) #DA00A66C cmyk(218,0,166,108)
       721: (218,  0,166,167) #DA00A6A7 cmyk(218,0,166,167)
       717: (218,  0,166,156) #DA00A69C cmyk(218,0,166,156)
       715: (218,  0,166, 97) #DA00A661 cmyk(218,0,166,97)
       714: (218,  0,166,172) #DA00A6AC cmyk(218,0,166,172)
       712: (218,  0,166,119) #DA00A677 cmyk(218,0,166,119)
       712: (218,  0,166,150) #DA00A696 cmyk(218,0,166,150)
       711: (218,  0,166,106) #DA00A66A cmyk(218,0,166,106)
       711: (218,  0,166, 85) #DA00A655 cmyk(218,0,166,85)
       708: (218,  0,166,151) #DA00A697 cmyk(218,0,166,151)
       708: (218,  0,166,155) #DA00A69B cmyk(218,0,166,155)
       707: (218,  0,166,179) #DA00A6B3 cmyk(218,0,166,179)
       706: (218,  0,166,154) #DA00A69A cmyk(218,0,166,154)
       706: (218,  0,166,152) #DA00A698 cmyk(218,0,166,152)
       704: (218,  0,166,138) #DA00A68A cmyk(218,0,166,138)
       703: (218,  0,166, 65) #DA00A641 cmyk(218,0,166,65)
       701: (218,  0,166,103) #DA00A667 cmyk(218,0,166,103)
       700: (218,  0,166, 99) #DA00A663 cmyk(218,0,166,99)
       700: (218,  0,166, 69) #DA00A645 cmyk(218,0,166,69)
       699: (218,  0,166,181) #DA00A6B5 cmyk(218,0,166,181)
       699: (218,  0,166,131) #DA00A683 cmyk(218,0,166,131)
       699: (218,  0,166, 68) #DA00A644 cmyk(218,0,166,68)
       698: (218,  0,166,158) #DA00A69E cmyk(218,0,166,158)
       696: (218,  0,166, 76) #DA00A64C cmyk(218,0,166,76)
       695: (218,  0,166,157) #DA00A69D cmyk(218,0,166,157)
       693: (218,  0,166,149) #DA00A695 cmyk(218,0,166,149)
       691: (218,  0,166,123) #DA00A67B cmyk(218,0,166,123)
       690: (218,  0,166, 86) #DA00A656 cmyk(218,0,166,86)
       690: (218,  0,166,110) #DA00A66E cmyk(218,0,166,110)
       690: (218,  0,166, 66) #DA00A642 cmyk(218,0,166,66)
       689: (218,  0,166,122) #DA00A67A cmyk(218,0,166,122)
       688: (218,  0,166,165) #DA00A6A5 cmyk(218,0,166,165)
       688: (218,  0,166,137) #DA00A689 cmyk(218,0,166,137)
       687: (218,  0,166,121) #DA00A679 cmyk(218,0,166,121)
       684: (218,  0,166,129) #DA00A681 cmyk(218,0,166,129)
       683: (218,  0,166,144) #DA00A690 cmyk(218,0,166,144)
       683: (218,  0,166, 82) #DA00A652 cmyk(218,0,166,82)
       682: (218,  0,166, 73) #DA00A649 cmyk(218,0,166,73)
       681: (218,  0,166, 93) #DA00A65D cmyk(218,0,166,93)
       681: (218,  0,166,145) #DA00A691 cmyk(218,0,166,145)
       679: (218,  0,166,136) #DA00A688 cmyk(218,0,166,136)
       679: (218,  0,166,107) #DA00A66B cmyk(218,0,166,107)
       678: (218,  0,166, 77) #DA00A64D cmyk(218,0,166,77)
       678: (218,  0,166,114) #DA00A672 cmyk(218,0,166,114)
       675: (218,  0,166,148) #DA00A694 cmyk(218,0,166,148)
       675: (218,  0,166,117) #DA00A675 cmyk(218,0,166,117)
       675: (218,  0,166, 70) #DA00A646 cmyk(218,0,166,70)
       674: (218,  0,166,130) #DA00A682 cmyk(218,0,166,130)
       674: (218,  0,166,139) #DA00A68B cmyk(218,0,166,139)
       673: (218,  0,166,109) #DA00A66D cmyk(218,0,166,109)
       672: (218,  0,166, 71) #DA00A647 cmyk(218,0,166,71)
       671: (218,  0,166, 74) #DA00A64A cmyk(218,0,166,74)
       671: (218,  0,166,133) #DA00A685 cmyk(218,0,166,133)
       671: (218,  0,166, 89) #DA00A659 cmyk(218,0,166,89)
       670: (218,  0,166, 87) #DA00A657 cmyk(218,0,166,87)
       670: (218,  0,166, 79) #DA00A64F cmyk(218,0,166,79)
       670: (218,  0,166, 92) #DA00A65C cmyk(218,0,166,92)
       669: (218,  0,166,134) #DA00A686 cmyk(218,0,166,134)
       668: (218,  0,166, 94) #DA00A65E cmyk(218,0,166,94)
       668: (218,  0,166,153) #DA00A699 cmyk(218,0,166,153)
       667: (218,  0,166,146) #DA00A692 cmyk(218,0,166,146)
       665: (218,  0,166, 91) #DA00A65B cmyk(218,0,166,91)
       665: (218,  0,166,142) #DA00A68E cmyk(218,0,166,142)
       663: (218,  0,166,161) #DA00A6A1 cmyk(218,0,166,161)
       663: (218,  0,166,141) #DA00A68D cmyk(218,0,166,141)
       662: (218,  0,166, 81) #DA00A651 cmyk(218,0,166,81)
       662: (218,  0,166,140) #DA00A68C cmyk(218,0,166,140)
       662: (218,  0,166,132) #DA00A684 cmyk(218,0,166,132)
       660: (218,  0,166,105) #DA00A669 cmyk(218,0,166,105)
       660: (218,  0,166, 95) #DA00A65F cmyk(218,0,166,95)
       656: (218,  0,166, 67) #DA00A643 cmyk(218,0,166,67)
       655: (218,  0,166,116) #DA00A674 cmyk(218,0,166,116)
       652: (218,  0,166,100) #DA00A664 cmyk(218,0,166,100)
       652: (218,  0,166,124) #DA00A67C cmyk(218,0,166,124)
       650: (218,  0,166,102) #DA00A666 cmyk(218,0,166,102)
       650: (218,  0,166,118) #DA00A676 cmyk(218,0,166,118)
       650: (218,  0,166,104) #DA00A668 cmyk(218,0,166,104)
       649: (218,  0,166,113) #DA00A671 cmyk(218,0,166,113)
       648: (218,  0,166, 75) #DA00A64B cmyk(218,0,166,75)
       647: (218,  0,166,127) #DA00A67F cmyk(218,0,166,127)
       643: (218,  0,166, 90) #DA00A65A cmyk(218,0,166,90)
       639: (218,  0,166, 72) #DA00A648 cmyk(218,0,166,72)
       635: (218,  0,166,111) #DA00A66F cmyk(218,0,166,111)
       635: (218,  0,166, 88) #DA00A658 cmyk(218,0,166,88)
       633: (218,  0,166, 83) #DA00A653 cmyk(218,0,166,83)
       631: (218,  0,166,101) #DA00A665 cmyk(218,0,166,101)
       631: (218,  0,166, 78) #DA00A64E cmyk(218,0,166,78)
       630: (218,  0,166, 98) #DA00A662 cmyk(218,0,166,98)
       628: (218,  0,166, 84) #DA00A654 cmyk(218,0,166,84)
       624: (218,  0,166,147) #DA00A693 cmyk(218,0,166,147)
       623: (218,  0,166,125) #DA00A67D cmyk(218,0,166,125)
       619: (218,  0,166,135) #DA00A687 cmyk(218,0,166,135)
       616: (218,  0,166,120) #DA00A678 cmyk(218,0,166,120)
       602: (218,  0,166,115) #DA00A673 cmyk(218,0,166,115)
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Matte color: grey74
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 1013x1556+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: None
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Properties:
    date:create: 2018-04-18T12:01:43+06:00
    date:modify: 2018-02-28T12:21:04+06:00
    dc:format: image/tiff
    exif:PixelXDimension: 1013
    exif:PixelYDimension: 1556
    icc:copyright: Copyright 2000 Adobe Systems, Inc.
    icc:description: U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2
    icc:manufacturer: U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2
    icc:model: U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2
    photoshop:ColorMode: 4
    photoshop:ICCProfile: U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2
    signature: a135bc6cdd2973e21c2c214d551a48f24f0591f38b110a200ff119efa15c3169
    tiff:alpha: unspecified
    tiff:endian: msb
    tiff:photometric: separated
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 2
    tiff:software: Adobe Photoshop CC 2017 (Macintosh)
    tiff:timestamp: 2018:02:26 15:04:14
    xmp:CreateDate: 2018-02-26T15:03:35-05:00
    xmp:CreatorTool: Adobe Photoshop CC 2017 (Macintosh)
    xmp:MetadataDate: 2018-02-26T15:04:14-05:00
    xmp:ModifyDate: 2018-02-26T15:04:14-05:00
    xmpMM:DocumentID: adobe:docid:photoshop:25b2dcd2-59ac-117b-8d68-a492c6c9a5f1
    xmpMM:InstanceID: xmp.iid:24fa47f2-26d3-4c6e-ac4d-01a88f4f5a76
    xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID: xmp.did:2ff1e3f6-3f01-4948-afcd-02cf577919bb
  Profiles:
    Profile-8bim: 6554 bytes
    Profile-icc: 557168 bytes
    Profile-xmp: 14615 bytes
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 6.884MB
  Number pixels: 1.576M
  Pixels per second: 40.42MB
  User time: 0.031u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.038
  Version: ImageMagick 7.0.5-2 Q16 x64 2017-03-11 http://www.imagemagick.org



 *6. Environment details : *  


    *imagemagick-transform.properties in alfresco-repository-*.jar   *
    # External executable locations
    img.root=./ImageMagick
    img.dyn=${img.root}/lib
    img.exe=${img.root}/bin/convert
    img.coders=${img.root}/modules/coders
    img.config=${img.root}/config
    img.gslib=${img.root}/lib

    *alfresco-global.properties*
    img.root=/opt/alfresco-one/common
    img.dyn=${img.root}/lib
    img.exe=${img.root}/bin/convert
    img.coders=/opt/alfresco-one/common/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.1/modules-Q16/coders
    img.config=/opt/alfresco-one/common/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.1/config-Q16
    img.gslib=${img.root}/lib
```

*6. Environment details : *

```
*imagemagick-transform.properties in alfresco-repository-*.jar   *
# External executable locations
img.root=./ImageMagick
img.dyn=${img.root}/lib
img.exe=${img.root}/bin/convert
img.coders=${img.root}/modules/coders
img.config=${img.root}/config
img.gslib=${img.root}/lib

*alfresco-global.properties*
img.root=/opt/alfresco-one/common
img.dyn=${img.root}/lib
img.exe=${img.root}/bin/convert
img.coders=/opt/alfresco-one/common/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.1/modules-Q16/coders
img.config=/opt/alfresco-one/common/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.1/config-Q16
img.gslib=${img.root}/lib
```

*I can see some version mismatch (there are 2 folder related to imagemagick exist in my centOS) *

[/opt/alfresco-one/common/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXiXj.png)

[/etc/ImageMagick-7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6SBR.png)

*I am not sure if i am using correct image magick path in alfresco-global.properties*

Comment: try using the full path to convert in your exec() command.

Comment: Thanks a lot fmw42 for your reply,    i tried this : Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/opt/alfresco-one/common/bin/convert -density 300 /home/alfresco-one/cms39/amicmyk.tif -profile /opt/alfresco-one/cit/rgbprofile/AdobeRGB1998.icc /opt/alfresco-one/Websites/amirgb.jpg");  but conversion is incorrect .       But same query work correctly when use in terminal.

Comment: `@deshi1`. I only see one AdobeRGB profile in your command. That would indicate that your input image had no profiles. Is that correct? If your input has a profile, then you only need to one AdobeRGB profile to convert to that form of RGB. But if your input has no profile, then you need to assign two profiles. The first to tell Imagemagick what the input space is (CMYK?) and the other to tell it what the output space should be (Adobe RGB). Perhaps you should post a link to your input TIFF, so it can be examine. Sorry I do not know your plugin tool.

Comment: I really thankful to you for helping me and your precious time,  i execute identify command, below is the out put and i updated the question with output o fidentify -verbose

Comment: amicmyk.tif TIFF 1013x1556 1013x1556+0+0 8-bit CMYK 6.884MB 0.016u 0:00.003

Comment: My plugin tool is normal alfresco sdk based Java app.

Comment: Your image does have a profile, so your command is correct. The fact that it works fine outside your alfresco confirms that. So the issue is with running imagemagick from alfresco. Unfortunately, I do not know alfresco. It looks like it is in your extra code, since you said it works fine in the one case. But as I do not know alfresco or java, I cannot help further.

Comment: Thanks a lot fmw42, I really appreciate your time and help, I will try analyse the alfresco part of the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your alfresco is configured to use imageMagick from /opt/alfresco-one/common/bin/ but in a OS terminal I assume you use the version from your linux distribution. The Alfresco ImageMagick version is handcrafted and maybe incomplete. You should configure alfresco to use the ImageMagick you use from command line.

e.g. in alfresco-global.properties

```
img.root=/etc/ImageMagick
img.config=/etc/ImageMagick
img.dyn=/usr/lib
img.exe=convert
img.coders=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/modules-Q16/coders
```

please check also imagemagick-transform.properties in alfresco-repository-*.jar

Comment: Thanks a lot @Heiko for helping me out , i am very new to CentOS and alfresco,       my all imagemagick conversion was working perfectly, just after adding the -profile changes in command problem occured,

I am using /opt/alfresco-one/common as my img.root   and please see the screenshot of  /etc/ImageMagick-7 , it has only some xmls . (last point 6. Environment details  )     i tried with /etc/ImageMagick-7 as img.root but it didnot work.

Comment: can i install image magick separately in CentOS with this existing ImageMagick? Actually i dont know what to tell my  enterprise team as comimand is working from terminal

Comment: I tried with the modified alfresco-global.properpies, but it didn't work

Comment: Thanks @Heiko and fmw42,  after knowing the the query was correct and i was not using correct version (as there were 2 different IM was installed ) of convert command, i finally able to correct the configuration and it works now